# Add computed column into existed table with rand() function

Tags: mysql, sql, alter

I have an existed table `product`, and want to add a new computed column `test`, with the formula is `SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 16)`

So the query is like this:

```
alter table product add test varchar(255) as (SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 16));
```

But it returns me the error is

```
Error Code: 3763. Expression of generated column 'test' contains a disallowed function: rand.
```

Do anyone know why and how to fix it?

Comment: 'For generated columns to work it is a requirement that the functions are deterministic, idempotent and side-effect free.'  I would say, it's not going to happen that way.  Can you insert those values instead?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html for rules. Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: @AllanWind  My purpose is like the auto-increment primary id when I insert the row

Comment: so only create table can create the computed column with my formula, but not for alter table?

Comment: You cannot use rand() in a generated column (irregardless if you use create or alter table).  Check out the link to the docs that @P.Salmon posted.

Comment: 'like auto-increment primary id' - in what way like? perhaps a uuid might be useful https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Comment: @AllanWind Does "irregardless" mean the opposite of "regardless", meaning "depends on"?

Comment: @Scratte it does not matter if you use create or alter table.  rand() is not allowed in a generated table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have stated in comments, you can't use `RAND()` in a computed column. But you can get the same intended result using a trigger.

First, add the column (I've called it `test_md5rand`):

```
ALTER TABLE product add test_md5rand varchar(255);
```

Then add the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER product_md5
BEFORE INSERT
ON product FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.test_md5rand = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 16);
END
```

Perhaps update the existing rows:

```
UPDATE product
   SET test_md5rand = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 16)
 WHERE test_md5rand IS NULL;
```

---

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c96b0bc15e76972d01c21985a17207b1)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add the value as a computed column -- the reason is simple:  the value changes on each execution.  Technically, this is because `rand()` is a *volatile* function.

If you *really* wanted this functionality, you could use a view:

```
create view v_product as
    select p.*, left(md5(rand()), 16) as test
    from product p;
```

Having value that changes is probably not what you want.  As the other answer suggests, you can use a trigger.  In my opinion, that is also unpleasant.

One option is to base the calculated value on existing columns, such as the name:

```
alter table product add test varchar(16) as left(md5(product_name), 16);
```

The only possible downside to this approach is that if the column changes, then `test` changes.